# QEPANET visualisation error

Tags: qepanet

I am new and not entirely sure if its just a setting. While using QEpanet, i can add a reservoir (R2), node, etc, and under the attributes table it appears. However it is not visible on the map.  It is located at bottom left of dialogue box - where the reservoir was placed.

Can you help?

[image: QEpanet]